# correlation estimation with non identical but independent multivariate normal samples

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, estimation, multivariate-analysis

Suppose there are $n$ k-dimensional multivariate normal distributions, each of them has the following form, with mean vector ${\mu_i}=[m_i,m_i,...,m_i]'$ of size $k$ by 1 and covariance matrix $\Sigma_i$ in the following of size $k$ by $k$. 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{i}^2 & \rho\sigma_{i}^2 & \rho\sigma_{i}^2 & \dots  & \rho\sigma_{i}^2 \\
    \rho\sigma_{i}^2 & \sigma_{i}^2 & \rho\sigma_{i}^2 & \dots  & \rho\sigma_{i}^2 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \rho\sigma_{i}^2 & \rho\sigma_{i}^2 & \rho\sigma_{i}^2 & \dots  & \sigma_{i}^2
\end{bmatrix} 
In essence, for each multivariate normal, the marginal distributions are the same. Among the multivariate normals, $m_i$ and $\sigma_i$ can be different but $\rho$ is the same across. These parameters are all unknown.

Now suppose we observe one observation (or one sample) from each multivariate normal independetly. In total, there are $n$ samples, forming the data of size $n$ by $k$. My question is: can we estimate $\rho$ using this data? What's the estimator? I believe the data has to be rescaled but not sure how.

Comment: Try maximum likelihood